# How to get opening hours from google places api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Here I have a code that works fine, so here is simple google places code that show me a places based on location and I add an label on every marker so:

http://jsbin.com/UqafeCI/4/edit - CODE and DEMO

Now I want to in label show opening time so I add to my code:

```
if (!!place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time) open = place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
```

and now my code looks like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      //THIS CODE I ADD TO PREVIOUS CODE THAT WORK, so if there is open time to show in label
      var open = 'No work time';
     if (!!place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time) open = place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;

      // Create a marker for each place.
     var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
       labelContent: open,
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
              labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0)
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
```

So how I can show open time of an object on label if time exist???

**UPDATE:**

I try to add request and service.getDetails function but again I cant get opening_time:

CODE:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();


    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
      var request =  {
          reference: place.reference
    };
      service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {

      var open = null;
      try{
  open = place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
}
catch(e){
  open='No work time';
}
      var otvoreno = place.openNow+"</br>"+place.name;

      // Create a marker for each place.
     var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
       labelContent: open,
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
              labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0)
      });
    });
      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
```

Comment: CODE updated: http://jsbin.com/IcIwIpUm/3/edit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a try-catch-statement:

```
try{
  open = place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
}
catch(e){
  open='No work time';
}
```

...otherwise you will get an error when any of following is undefined:

- `place.opening_hours`
- `place.opening_hours.periods`
- `place.opening_hours.periods[1]`
- `place.opening_hours.periods[1].open`

But however, the documentation seems to be misleading, it suggests that the returned results are [placeDetails](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResponses). But that's not the fact , you need a further request for each place to [request the placeDetails](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests)(which will contain the `opening_hours.periods`, when available)

Comment: It's not christmas yet ;)

Comment: but its by 2 days, so this will be my Christmas present :D THANKS! please update with placeDetails function

Comment: just give me a idea where to put getplace request

Comment: As you can see I update my question, but again this code isn't work. Why? Where is problem now? I cant see? sorry for my english

Comment: There a limits for requests, for  all Webservices there is a basic limit of 10 requests per second. You'll need to request the details with a increasing delay. Fixed example: http://jsbin.com/ATaZEXE/1/edit

Comment: ok, thanks but now I just see etc. 12:00 so just open time, not close time there... and my user location navigator dont work...

Comment: I've removed the geolocation-part in my  example, because it's not important for the issue. When you wan't to see the closing-time too you must fetch the close-property in the same manner as the open-property