# How to get opening_hours using the Google Places API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm working with the [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) and I want to have access to the **opening hours** information. I have searched and in the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) the atribute `opening_hours` is abailable, but in the documentation you can read:

> The Google Places API Web Service should be used in server applications. If you're building a client-side app, check out the Google Places API for Android and Site Library in Google Maps JavaScript API.

Here is object [Place](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Places) - from Google Apis for Android. 
And here the [result](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) of the details of one place - from Places Api W.S.

How can I get the **opening hours** of one place using the api for Android? Is that possible? May I use the api for W.S even what google says?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735016/how-to-get-opening-hours-from-google-places-api#20735595

Comment: @MCZ that's not an answer, that is for javascript, ! 

But I was asking if I can work with  *Places API Web Service* in the client side (**Android**) !? Or there is a way using the *api for Android*!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code : read all comment line  carefully .

```
// A class to parse the Google Place Details in JSON format 
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, HashMap<String,String>>{

        JSONObject jObject;
        @Override
        protected HashMap<String,String> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            HashMap<String, String> hPlaceDetails = null;
            PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();

            try{
                // this object give JSON
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // this object give Result
                JSONObject jresult = new JSONObject(jObject[1]);            

                // this object give opening_hours
                JSONObject jopening_hours = new JSONObject(jresult[2]);

                // this object give periods
                JSONObject jperiods = new JSONObject(jopening_hours[2]);



            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return jperiods;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JsonObject periods){
                HashMap<String,String> periods;

                // put your condition 
                for(..)
                {
                JsonObject day = new JSONObject(periods[i]);
                    periods.put("key",day.get("day"));

                } 
              }
    }
```

**[0] for Monday and [6] for Sunday**

JSON look like
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json placeid=ChIJKfCbbyyNWTkRAPM1frrO_sM&key=YOUR_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJKfCbbyyNWTkRAPM1frrO_sM&key=YOUR_API_KEY)

Beautify json file : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Sorry for the delay response, did you used this api? because I'm not able to use it in the Android Client, because I'm getting invalid key.

Comment: It work perfectly .. this is live code in my project

Comment: This url work in browser or not check it first ? if any error please tell me

Comment: Harsil, I was having problems with the url and the api key, now its works, but I'm not sure this is ok because of _"If you're building a client-side app, check out the Google Places API for Android and Site Library in Google Maps JavaScript API."_ what do you think? Thanks you very muchl!!

Comment: i use "Google Places API Web Service" in Android and iOS both. i know there is other option "Google Places Android API" also after some year ago there is only one option  Web Service API so i use this . and second problem is some country Google Places iOS sdk give wrong suggestion and Web API work perfect .